# Expired Iranian passport with Canadian PR Card wanted to fly from Toronto to Tehran Iran

Tags: international-travel, passport-renewals, iranian-citizens, canadian-residents, expired

My wife Iranian citizen with Canadian Permanent Residence Card wanted to fly to Iran with Iranian passport expired on January 8, 2023. Is it possible to travel to iran and which airlines allow it. In Canada there is no Iranian embassy so she can only get new passport from iran once she reach there. Please advise best solution for that?

Comment: Some people on the internet say they have been able to renew Iranian passports from Canada by contacting the [Iranian Interests Section of the Pakistan Embassy in Washington, DC](https://daftar.org/); I can't read Persian so can't tell you what their website says about the topic, but you might consider contacting them to see if they can help and so you can avoid the problem of traveling with an expired passport.

Comment: See answer posted here: [Can I fly from the US to Iran with an expired Iranian passport? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/179020/95267)